# How to use Swagger @ApiResponses annotation in Kotlin?

Tags: java, annotations, kotlin, swagger

How to convert the following Swagger annotations from Java to Kotlin?

```
 @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Given admin user found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "..."),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "..."),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "..."),
            @ApiResponse(code = 412, message = "...") })
```

This does not works:

```
@ApiResponses(value = listOf( 
        ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "..."),
        ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "..."),
        ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "..."),
        ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "..."),
        ApiResponse(code = 412, message = "...") ))
```

The error is:

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is List but ApiResponse was expected

It works when I use just one `@ApiResponse` instead of `listOf()`, but I have to define more `@ApiResponse(s)`.

I use Swagger 2.5.0

Comment: Annotations expect Arrays, not Lists, so try using the `arrayOf`-function instead of `listOf()`

Comment: Now I have got error: `Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Array<ApiResponse> but ApiResponse was expected`

Comment: Yeah this is very odd. I'm tempted to say this might be a bug in Kotlin

Comment: Just tried it, actually you need to completly leave out the `value = listOf` part, and just put the individual arguments top level. Seems like kotlin translates a `value` that's an Array into varargs when called from Kotlin.

Comment: See my answer for the section in the Kotlin language reference that covers this and the code example that should work for you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As stated in [the Kotlin Language Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#java-annotations):

> If the value argument [of an Annotation] in Java has an array type, it becomes a vararg parameter in Kotlin

So, to make your example work, you need to put it like so:

```
@ApiResponses(
    ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "..."),
    ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "..."),
    ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "..."),
    ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "..."),
    ApiResponse(code = 412, message = "...")
)
```

Comment: For Swagger 3, use `responseCode` in stead of `code`

Answer (score 11):

For Swagger 3, this is the way to go:

```
 @ApiResponses(value = [
    ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "...", content = [
        (Content(mediaType = "application/json", array = (
        ArraySchema(schema = Schema(implementation = DataModel::class)))))]),
    ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "...", content = [Content()]),
    ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "...", content = [Content()])]
    )
```

This snippet also includes `@Content`, `@ArraySchema` and `@Schema` annotation examples.

Comment: The varargs approach in the accepted answer also works with Swagger 3

Comment: Also, you can use `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` instead of the `"application/json"` magic string.